# Use make file to generate database from .sql file

Tags: ios, sql, xcode, sqlite

I have a .sql file that has all the create statements for the tables in my database (ie CREATE TABLE X, CREATE INDEX Y, CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Z). Is it possible to write a makefile that can easily run this code and generate the tables?

Additionally, would it be possible to connect this to Xcode so that when I run my app the database is created?

Comment: Which do you want? Do you want the database file created during a build or do you want to create the database file in your app? You should only do one or the other, not both.

Comment: eventually I want it to be run through xcode, but I'd like to know how to do both if they are both possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sqlite3_exec` to run your `sql` file at runtime in your app. Of course you only want to do it once. You need to use `sqlite2_open_v2` to open a new database file first, then execute the `sql` file.

If you want to generate the database file in Xcode during a build, you can do this after some setup. I do this in one of my projects.

Start by selecting your target in Xcode and going to the "Build Phases" tab. Then click on the "Add Build Phase" button and select "Add Run Script". Double-click on the "Run Script" title and rename it to something useful such as "Generate db file".

Change the "shell" value to "/bin/bash".

Use the following for the script:

```
cd database
if [ create.sql -nt data.db ]; then
   rm -rf empty.db
fi

if [ ! -e data.db ]; then
   sqlite3 data.db < create.sql
fi
cd -
```

You probably need to change a few details of this script. Given that the script will be run from the root directory of your project, change the first line (`cd database`) to reflect where your `sql` file is within your own project. Then change any references to `create.sql` to match the name of your own `sql` file. And last, change any references to `data.db` to match what you want your database file to be named.

The last step is to move this build phase to before the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase. Also make sure the `db` file ends up in your resources.

The script will update the `db` file any time the `sql` file is updated.